# Como recorrer y guardar los datos de un array desde el 1er índice en PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un sitio sobre arriendo de cabañas y tengo 2 problemas que no se muy bien cómo solucionarlos, el primero es para guardar múltiples registros y el segundo es que el método save() de laravel no guarda.

Tengo un array el cual pertenece a un rango de fechas seleccionadas.

En el obtengo las fechas introducidas en un form las cuales son enviadas a validar al controlador.

Resulta que quiero guardar ese array en mi base de datos, pero no quiero que se guarden los mismos registros en 2 campos que tengo destinados para aquello de una tabla de mi base de datos, explico:

Se seleccionó un rango de fechas desde el **`1-12-2018`** hasta el **`01-12-2018.`** Con un horario desde las **08:00:00** hasta las **23:00:00 Hrs.**

Luego en el controlador valido aquello de la siguiente manera.

```
public function store(Request $request){
  try {
    foreach($request->horario as $id_horario=>$row){    
      foreach($row['check'] as $check){

        $startdate = $row['desde'];
        $endate = $row['hasta'];

        $period = CarbonPeriod::create($startdate, $endate);

        $dates = $times = [];

        $tstart = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_inicio']);
        $tend = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_termino']);

        while ($tstart < $tend) {
            $times[] = $tstart->format("H:i:s");
            $tstart->addHour();
        }

        foreach($period as $date){
            foreach($times as $time){
                $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $time;
            }
        }

        $horarios = new HorariosNew();

        $horarios->hora_inicio = $dates;
        $horarios->hora_fin = $dates[1];

        $horarios->estado_horario_id = $row['estado_horario_id'];
        $horarios->cancha_id = $check;
        $horarios->save();
    }
  }
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
    return redirect()->route('horarios.store');
  }

  Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
  return redirect()->route('horarios.store');     
}
```

En donde dice `$horarios->hora_fin = $dates[1];` logré que me trajera el dato del array desde la primera ubicación, pero el problema es que no sé muy bien cómo hacer que en vez de que me muestre solo el valor del array en el índice 1. Me muestre el array completo **comenzando** desde el 1er índice.

Ya que intento guardar un registro múltiple de manera que me quede de esta forma en una tabla de mi base de datos.

```
`MI TABLA HORARIO`

id |fecha_inicio       |fecha_fin          |estado_horario_id|cancha_id
931|2018-12-01 08:00:00|2018-12-01 09:00:00|                1|        2
932|2018-12-01 09:00:00|2018-12-01 10:00:00|                1|        2
933|2018-12-01 10:00:00|2018-12-01 11:00:00|                1|        2
934|2018-12-01 11:00:00|2018-12-01 12:00:00|                1|        2
935|2018-12-01 12:00:00|2018-12-01 13:00:00|                1|        2
936|2018-12-01 13:00:00|2018-12-01 14:00:00|                1|        2
937|2018-12-01 14:00:00|2018-12-01 15:00:00|                1|        2
938|2018-12-01 15:00:00|2018-12-01 16:00:00|                1|        2   
939|2018-12-01 16:00:00|2018-12-01 17:00:00|                1|        2
940|2018-12-01 17:00:00|2018-12-01 18:00:00|                1|        2
941|2018-12-01 18:00:00|2018-12-01 19:00:00|                1|        2
942|2018-12-01 19:00:00|2018-12-01 20:00:00|                1|        2
943|2018-12-01 20:00:00|2018-12-01 21:00:00|                1|        2
944|2018-12-01 21:00:00|2018-12-01 22:00:00|                1|        2
945|2018-12-01 22:00:00|2018-12-01 23:00:00|                1|        2
```

En donde dice `fecha_fin` se ve que comienza desde 1 hora adelantada en comparación con el campo `fecha_inicio`, siendo así como intento que guarde el array.

Al momento de realizar un `dd($horarios->hora_inicio, $horarios->hora_fin);` obtengo lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el segundo array que aparece corresponde al campo **`fecha_fin`** de mi tabla y es también en donde el array debería comenzar desde el 1er índice (siempre), ya que no se puede guardar 2 horarios idénticos.

Quedando finalmente de esta manera:

```
array:8[
  0 => "2018-12-12 08:00:00" /*OMITIENDO ESTE*/
  1 => "2018-12-12 09:00:00" /*GUARDAR DE AQUÍ EN ADELANTE*/
  2 => "2018-12-12 10:00:00"
  3 => "2018-12-12 11:00:00"
  4 => "2018-12-13 08:00:00" /*ESTE TAMBIÉN OMITIRLO*/
  5 => "2018-12-13 09:00:00" /*SEGUIR DE AQUÍ EN ADELANTE*/
  6 => "2018-12-13 10:00:00"
  7 => "2018-12-13 11:00:00"
]
```

Además, no me guarda como debe ser. Debe ser un array completamente, es decir de la misma manera como muestra el ejemplo de la tabla. De momento lo único que es array son las fechas, los demás campos los guarda solos.

De esta manera: (Realice un `dd($horarios)` para ver de que manera me guarda los datos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último al momento de guardar obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La generación de la fecha final es un poco confusa, ¿no sería más fácil agregarle una hora a dicha fecha/hora final antes de almacenarla?

Comment: no se si te e entendido bien lo que quieres pero solo que se almacene en tu tabla como muestras noo... podrias publicar lo que recibes por $request->horario?

Comment: @Bryro. Si en un principio era el tema de los arrays pero como le encontré la solución ya, me falta solucionar el problema que guarde en la base de datos, ya que como mencioné no guarda y arroja ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear múltiples registros usa el comando create() en vez de save(), usando solamente un array de php, no una instancia de un modelo de Eloquent, para ello crea tu array:

Creamos el arreglo para cada ítem:

```
$c = count($dates);

for( $i=0;$i<$c;$i++ )
{
    $horarios[]= [
        'hora_incio'        => $dates[$i],
        'hora_fin'          => $dates_2[$i],
        'estado_horario_id' => $row['estado_horario_id´],
        'cancha_id'         => $check
    ];
}
```

Después solo queda guardarlo en tu BD:

```
HorariosNew::create($horarios);
```

Comment: Luego de probar eso, el error se mantiene. En ambos casos.

Comment: ¿Puedes subir foto del error usando el código que escribí?

Comment: Si, si puedo veamos.

Comment: Puedes poner un link aqui en los comentarios.

Comment: Mira realice un dd($horarios) para ver lo que se recibe. Puedes revisar la imagen siguiendo este enlace: [FOTO1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Rv_nnJnNTmQYsMoDxWDQsVEa17f4oH4/view)

Comment: Y con respecto al código lo utilice de la misma manera como me lo presentabas, probando de las 2 formas. [1 Forma](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gg2-iD6ONysv3IACaV8dBiz3sPOplyk4/view), [2 Forma](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WN7ZzwaIl_yK425qeTLOS20a9ps1H6lT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Edité mi respuesta original, intenta probar por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Posteo una solución al 1er problema que mencioné. De momento he logrado solucionar el primer problema de los arrays. Por cada dia sumará 1 hora al 2do array, y también para cada vez que comienza sumará 1 hora también.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    try {
        foreach($request->horario as $id_horario=>$row){    
            foreach($row['check'] as $check){

                $startdate = $row['desde'];
                $endate = $row['hasta'];

                $period = CarbonPeriod::create($startdate, $endate);
                $period_2 = CarbonPeriod::create($startdate, $endate);

                $dates = $times = [];
                $dates_2 = $times_2 = [];

                $tstart = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_inicio']);
                $tend = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_termino']);

                $tstart_2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_inicio']);
                $tstart_2->modify('+1 hour');

                $tend_2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_termino']);

                while ($tstart < $tend){
                    $times[] = $tstart->format("H:i:s");
                    $tstart->addHour();
                }
                while ($tstart_2 <= $tend_2) {

                    $times_2[] = $tstart_2->format('H:i:s');
                    $tstart_2->addHour();
                }
                foreach($period as $date){
                    foreach($times as $time){
                        $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $time;

                    }
                }
                foreach ($period_2 as $date_2) {
                    foreach ($times_2 as $time_2) {
                        $dates_2[] = $date_2->format('Y-m-d'). " ".$time_2;
                    }
                }

                $horarios = new HorariosNew();

                $horarios->hora_inicio = $dates;
                $horarios->hora_fin = $dates_2;

                $horarios->estado_horario_id = $row['estado_horario_id'];
                $horarios->cancha_id = $check;  
                dd($horarios->hora_inicio, $horarios->hora_fin);
                $horarios->save();
            }
        }
    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
         return redirect()->route('horarios.store');
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
    return redirect()->route('horarios.store');     
}
```

Al realizar un `dd($horarios->hora_inicio, $horarios->hora_fin);` se obtiene lo siguiente:

```
array:30 [▼
  0 => "2018-12-12 08:00:00"
  1 => "2018-12-12 09:00:00"
  2 => "2018-12-12 10:00:00"
  3 => "2018-12-12 11:00:00"
  4 => "2018-12-12 12:00:00"
  5 => "2018-12-12 13:00:00"
  6 => "2018-12-12 14:00:00"
  7 => "2018-12-12 15:00:00"
  8 => "2018-12-12 16:00:00"
  9 => "2018-12-12 17:00:00"
 10 => "2018-12-12 18:00:00"
 11 => "2018-12-12 19:00:00"
 12 => "2018-12-12 20:00:00"
 13 => "2018-12-12 21:00:00"
 14 => "2018-12-12 22:00:00"
 15 => "2018-12-13 08:00:00"
 16 => "2018-12-13 09:00:00"
 17 => "2018-12-13 10:00:00"
 18 => "2018-12-13 11:00:00"
 19 => "2018-12-13 12:00:00"
 20 => "2018-12-13 13:00:00"
 21 => "2018-12-13 14:00:00"
 22 => "2018-12-13 15:00:00"
 23 => "2018-12-13 16:00:00"
 24 => "2018-12-13 17:00:00"
 25 => "2018-12-13 18:00:00"
 26 => "2018-12-13 19:00:00"
 27 => "2018-12-13 20:00:00"
 28 => "2018-12-13 21:00:00"
 29 => "2018-12-13 22:00:00"
]
//----------------------------------
array:30 [▼
  0 => "2018-12-12 09:00:00"
  1 => "2018-12-12 10:00:00"
  2 => "2018-12-12 11:00:00"
  3 => "2018-12-12 12:00:00"
  4 => "2018-12-12 13:00:00"
  5 => "2018-12-12 14:00:00"
  6 => "2018-12-12 15:00:00"
  7 => "2018-12-12 16:00:00"
  8 => "2018-12-12 17:00:00"
  9 => "2018-12-12 18:00:00"
 10 => "2018-12-12 19:00:00"
 11 => "2018-12-12 20:00:00"
 12 => "2018-12-12 21:00:00"
 13 => "2018-12-12 22:00:00"
 14 => "2018-12-12 23:00:00"
 15 => "2018-12-13 09:00:00"
 16 => "2018-12-13 10:00:00"
 17 => "2018-12-13 11:00:00"
 18 => "2018-12-13 12:00:00"
 19 => "2018-12-13 13:00:00"
 20 => "2018-12-13 14:00:00"
 21 => "2018-12-13 15:00:00"
 22 => "2018-12-13 16:00:00"
 23 => "2018-12-13 17:00:00"
 24 => "2018-12-13 18:00:00"
 25 => "2018-12-13 19:00:00"
 26 => "2018-12-13 20:00:00"
 27 => "2018-12-13 21:00:00"
 28 => "2018-12-13 22:00:00"
 29 => "2018-12-13 23:00:00"
]
```

Aunque aun no logro solucionar el 2do problema, que no guarda los datos.

Answer (score 0):

imagino que esto es lo que buscas aunque no te e entendido del todo bien:
puedo seguir editandola:

```
foreach($period as $date) { 
    foreach($times as $time) { 
        $horarios = new HorariosNew();
        $horarios->hora_inicio = $date->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $time;
        $horarios->hora_fin = $date->format('Y-m-d'). " ".$time;

        $horarios->estado_horario_id = $row['estado_horario_id'];
        $horarios->cancha_id = $check;  
        $horarios->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Al probar eso me arroja el siguiente error: `Cannot use object of type Carbon\Carbon as array`

Comment: intentalo ahora a ver?

Comment: Amigo sigue igual.

Comment: tienes 2 variables $date una creada con carbon y la otras como un alias en foreach! intentalo ahora!

Comment: Ahora dice otro error: `Method format does not exist` y para el estado_horario_id no uso `$request`, de esta manera me trae datos: `$row['estado_horario_id'];`

Comment: mejor corrige el codigo antes de publicarlo ya que sale que lo utilizas asi en tus 2 ejemplos ... :v  `$horarios->estado_horario_id = $request->estado_horario_id;`

Comment: ¿Así como? Te refieres al for() porque si es así, yo en mi código no utilizo un for() y cree 2 variables que son similares porque a la 2da le sumo la hora.

Comment: el for es para hacer referencia los 2 times ya que ambos tienen las misma dimenciones no es necesario 2 loop :v y ya deberia funcionarte como esta!